# Restoring an object to its original form after being used on boolean

Tags: modifiers, objects

Without deleting the default cube, I added another object, an icosphere.

I used the icosphere to perform boolean subtract to the default cube.

Then I decided to duplicate the icosphere that was already used for boolean subtract.

Question: How do I restore the duplicated icosphere into its original form before I used it for boolean subtract?

This is probably basic, but I couldn't find any information about it on the internet. I've been tinkering for quite some time now so I decided to stop wasting my time and just ask here.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set up the modifier on the first *Icosphere* the *Viewport Display* was changed to *Bounds*.

To fix this:

- Select *Icosphere.001*
- Go to the *Properties Editor* -> *Object Properties* and open the *Viewport Display* panel.
  -In the *Viewport Display* panel change *Display as* to *Textured* by left clicking on *Bounds* and selecting *Textured* from the dropdown menu:

[image: Viewport Display showing Display As being changed]

This is part of a fairly common workflow for non-destructive Boolean modeling.  The Icosphere is called a *cutter* in this workflow and its viewport display is set to either Bounds or Wire.  This is so you can have an idea where the Boolean object (cutter) is, but you can also see what it is accomplishing -- as you move it around.

The normal setting of *Display As* for non-cutter objects is *Textured*.  This is slightly misleading.  The way that *Display As* works is that it sets the maximum that will be displayed; but the Viewport settings in the header control how close to the maximum the viewport display will really be:

[image: The viewport display settings]

If *Wireframe* is chosen from that menu, then objects will all be shown as either bounds or wire.  If *Solid* is chosen, then objects that are set to Display as *Solid* or *Textured* will be displayed as Solid.

Comment: ugh, I knew it was easy, I didn't know it was this easy. I must be very tired to have missed that. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: It's easy to miss things in Blender, even after you've used it for years.  There's a lot there to remember.